# What is the right way to handle Strings when doing HTTP requests?

Tags: android, http, retrofit

I have an Android application acting as a client to my back end server.

I am doing a `POST` http request with a help of Retrofit lib with a String in the body.

Problem is, Retrofit is most likely escaping double quotes when using GSON builder.

That results in a field in my DB containing double quotes, example: `"example_gcm_token"`.

I need to know whether I should handle that on server side or on client side and how to do that.

I assume it shouldn't be on the server side as it would mean I have to remove escaped quotes for every single endpoint.

```
@POST ("/Maguss/users/{userId}/gcmtoken")
    Call<Void> setGcmToken(@Path("userId") Long userId, @Body StringEntity gcmToken);
```

Comment: So the returned json actually looks something like: ``{ "some key": "\"example_gcm_token\"" }``?

Comment: Then I don't know of any other way either to strip it in the client or backend. I still think logic like this should be in the backend, but this can be just a matter of taste. I do think the backend should always be somehow the single point of truth and where everything gets built. It also seems like the quotes should not even be in the string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would try to replace the `StringEntity` with a POJO:

```
public class SetGcmTokenRequest {
    @SerializedName("gcmtoken")
    private String gcmToken;

    public String getGcmToken() {
        return gcmToken;
    }

    public void setGcmToken(String gcmToken) {
        this.gcmToken = gcmToken;
    }
}
```

And change the interface like this:

```
@POST ("/Maguss/users/{userId}/gcmtoken")
Call<Void> setGcmToken(@Path("userId") Long userId, @Body SetGcmTokenRequest setGcmTokenRequest);
```

Comment: Yeah that would solve it, though I am not happy I cant send simple strings without having to deal with quotes :)

Comment: I know, but I don't think StringEntity is supported as a body. You could use HashMap<String, String>, but then your API client would become a guessing game :)